# Can't retrieve a number of document into firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a small problem, I need to retrieve into my list a collection retrieved by StreamBuilder from Firestore.
I am using `snapshot.data.documents.lenght`  but once I add it I got error:

```
Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: documents
```

this is my code:

```
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getDatabase() async* {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection('dataCollection')
        .document(user.uid)
        .snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getDatabase(),
      builder: (context, snapshot,) {
        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 500,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 2,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                      color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                      elevation: 15,
                      child: Text(
                        snapshot.data['phone']..
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Firestore does not retrieve documents recursively.

Comment: user fill a form and once the user filled the form these data will go into a list, each item of this list yes a documents from firestore. thus I need that each time the user fill my form an item in the list is created, but I need the lenght of the collection from the user

Comment: You need to get the collection itself then, not the Document parent.

Comment: ok but How to to implement my code with that?

Comment: You need to specify what collection you need the length of.

Comment: snapshot.data.collection['nameOfCollection'].lenght is that correct?

Comment: No it is not. Look at the documentation, that is not valid. It has to be changed in `getDatabase`.

Answer (score 0):

just change your code as following

```
Stream dataStream
```

then

```
   @override
  void initState() {
    getDatabase().then((value) {
      dataStream = value;
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

the funcion getDatbase()

```
getDatabase() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance
        .collection('dataCollection')
        .document(user.uid)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

then

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: dataStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot,) {
        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 500,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 2,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                      color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                      elevation: 15,
                      child: Text(
                        snapshot.data['phone']..
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: stream,
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshots) {
                if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
                    snapshots.hasData) {
                  return Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshots.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        
                      //do something with snapshot.

                        
                          }
                        }
                        return Container();
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              },
            ),
```

Initialise your stream like this,

```
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> stream;
  Future<dynamic> getDatabase() async {
    

    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   
  
    setState(() {
    
      stream=Firestore.instance
        .collection('dataCollection')
        .document(user.uid)
        .snapshots();
    });
  }
```

You can call getDatabase() in initState.

Update:-

This is your full code.

```
class DataCo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          CollectData(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class CollectData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CollectDataState createState() => _CollectDataState();
}

class _CollectDataState extends State<CollectData> {
  final String phone;
  final String wife;
  final String location;

  _CollectDataState({this.phone, this.wife, this.location});


@override
  void initState() {
 super.initState();
    getDatabase();
     
   
  }

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> stream;
  Future<dynamic> getDatabase() async {



    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();


    setState(() {

      stream=Firestore.instance
        .collection('dataCollection')
        .document(user.uid)
        .snapshots();
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,) {
    return StreamBuilder(
              stream: stream,
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots) {
                if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
                    snapshots.hasData) {
                  return Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshots.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                      //do something with snapshot.


                          }
                        }
                        return Container();
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              },
            );
  }
}

class NoData extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('No Data available'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: error again the problem is with my class; Stream<DocumentSnapshot> that need to retieve userdata from firestore

Comment: @TiziDev i have added the full code, see if this works

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: To debug, you can try printing the snapshot, see what it contains

Comment: hello thanks for the effort but I got lenght error: The getter 'lenght' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'.

Comment: Dude, the spelling is wrong, correct it..it should be length

Comment: Call getDatabase() in initState

Comment: added: 
 @override
  void initState() {
    getDatabase().then((value) {
      dataStream = value;
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }
but nothing

Comment: @TiziDev i have updated my answer, please check. i have added the initState

Comment: I see you adding on InitState the getDatabas() but still on lenght I get the same error: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'.

Comment: if you put the code on Android studio u see the errors

Comment: it's happening because your data is not a list. retrieve your doc contents based on how you document is structured

Comment: as you can see: https://codeshare.io/GA47Dx these is a list